# Non linear system of equations in matrix form - Python

Tags: python, matrix, nonlinear-equation

I am dealing with a non linear system of equations in matrix form in python, namely:

F=Af+b(F)

Where F is my uknown vector 9x1, A is a known 9x9 matrix, f is a known 9x1 vector and b(F) is a 9x1 vector which is non linear function of the components of F.

How can i put this whole thing in a non linear equation solver?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. Check if this helps you

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.randn(9, 9)
f = np.random.randn(9,1)
b_f = np.random.randn(9,1)

F = np.dot(A, f) + b_f
```

Comment: Hmmm no, my question is how to solve the non linear system of equations F-Af-b(F)=0